# Get name and version from a dictionary formatted facts

Tags: ansible

Below ansible tasks display pip packages in dictionary format.

```yaml
- name: Ganther pip packages
  pip_package_info:
    clients: pip3
  register: pip_pkgs
```

And the output is:

```json
{
  "packages": {
    pip3: {
      "xxx": [
        {
          name: "xxx"
          source: "pip3"
          version: "1.0.0"
        }
      ],
      "yyy": [
        {
          name: "yyy"
          source: "pip3"
          version: "2.0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to loop through the registered variable, but, I am getting errors about undefined variable. How to get the name and version from the above dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`values`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.values) method of the Python dictionary in order to have something that you could loop on:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }} is in version {{ item.version }}"
  loop: "{{ pip_pkgs.packages.pip3.values() | flatten }}"
```

Alternatively, it can also be achieved with `dict2items`, but makes the loop syntax a little bit longer, since you then have to `map` the attribute you are interested in — here, the value:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }} is in version {{ item.version }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      pip_pkgs.packages.pip3
      | dict2items
      | map(attribute='value')
      | flatten
    }}
```

---

If you want to create a dictionary, this would be the easiest:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    pip_packages: >-
      {{
        dict(
          _pip_pkg | map(attribute='name')
          | zip(_pip_pkg | map(attribute='version'))
        )
      }}
  vars:
    _pip_pkg: "{{ pip_pkgs.packages.pip3.values() | flatten }}"
```

The dictionary would look like

```yaml
pip_packages:
  ansible: 5.6.0
  ansible-compat: 2.0.2
  ansible-core: 2.12.4
  ansible-lint: 6.0.2
```

---

Given the two tasks:

```yaml
- pip_package_info:
    clients: pip3
  register: pip_pkgs

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }} is in version {{ item.version }}"
  loop: "{{ pip_pkgs.packages.pip3.values() | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

This gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible) => 
  msg: ansible is in version 5.6.0
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible-compat) => 
  msg: ansible-compat is in version 2.0.2
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible-core) => 
  msg: ansible-core is in version 2.12.5
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible-lint) => 
  msg: ansible-lint is in version 6.0.2

... list goes on
```

Comment: Thanks you now I am able to store key value pair in another dictionary
``
- name: Store
  set_fact: 
      my_dct: "{{ my_dict | default([]) + [ {'name:item.name, ;version':item.version}] }}"
  loop: "{{ pip_pkgs.packages.pip3.values() | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
     lable: "{{ item.name }}"
``

Comment: There is easier than that for a dictionary. See updated answer.